# Framerate drop on the clock tower level?

Tags: fez

Has anyone else run into a massive framerate drop for (what I think is) the clock tower level? It drops to about 1fps as soon as I enter the area. If I leave through the door I came in from, the framerate returns to normal, but tanks again as soon as I go back through. I restarted the game but it started lagging immediately upon loading the level. Opening the menus is still smooth, but as they animate away the framerate drops again.

I made a video of it here:

I have a 250 GB hard drive for my 360, so it shouldn't be related to the small HDD problem(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a noted bug: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/961239-fez/62545192

Comment: Ah thanks. I had Googled around and didn't find anything, but didn't think to check GameFAQs.